# return array from c# function to js var

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Hi I am trying to pass an array to js from c# but it keep telling me compilation error. Here is my code:

**C#.net**

```
public string calls()
{
    string[] listing = new string[5];
    listing[0] = "20-05-2015";
    listing[1] = "22-05-2015";
    listing[2] = "24-05-2015";
    listing[3] = "26-05-2015";
    listing[4] = "28-05-2015";
    string jsonlisting = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listing);
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('" + jsonlisting + "')", true);
    return jsonlisting;
}
```

**jquery/javascript**

```
<script>
    function pageLoad() {
        var unavailableDates = <%=this.calls();%>        
    );
</script>
```

Comment: the message just return "compilation error".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the semi-colon directly after calls().  The following simplified version worked for me in an example I created:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var unavailableDates = <%= this.calls() %>
</script>
```